# Cannot set android sdk location in xamarin studio due to hidden folders

Tags: android, xamarin-studio, hidden-files

I'm on a mac. I installed android studio and it put the sdk in the default location `'/Users/koushiksarkar/Library/Android/sdk'`.

Now after installing xamarin studio I need to set the sdk location. But while browsing for the path I can see under `'/Users/koushiksarkar/'` `'library'` is a hidden folder.

Now I have my hidden folders shown by running `'defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES'` in the terminal. So from Finder window I can navigate to that path.

But while browsing from xamarin studio, trying to set sdk location, I'm unable to browse to the path. Any help?

Comment: Don't browse, then. Type it manually

Comment: With the browser open, `CMD-Shift-G` and type in the `~/Library` or as cricket says, just type it in manually...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. After typing it manually I can run apps on emulator. But when I try to launch the SDK manager or AVD manager from inside xamarin studio (Tools -> SDK Manager), nothing happens